# Rails precision error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, precision

When I run this in my Rails application:

```
my_envelope.transactions.sum(:amount)
```

This SQL is shown in the log files:

```
SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT SUM("transactions"."amount") AS sum_id FROM "transactions" WHERE (envelope_id = 834498537)
```

And this value is returned:

```
<BigDecimal:1011be570,'0.2515999999 9999997E2',27(27)>
```

As you can see, the value is 25.159999. It should be 25.16. When I run the same SQL on the database myself, the correct value is returned.

I'm a little confused because I know that there are precision problems with Floats, but it is returning a BigDecimal. The SQL column type is decimal. I'm using using sqlite3 (3.6.17) and sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2). Any ideas?

**Update 1**

Here are the results when I run this directly using the SQLite3-ruby interface.

```
$ rails c test
Loading test environment (Rails 3.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> db = SQLite3::Database.new("db/test.sqlite3")
=> #<SQLite3::Database:0x5242020>
irb(main):002:0> db.execute("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE envelope_id = 834498537")
=> [[25.159999999999997]]
```

The class of that number is Float. btw, the three numbers it sums are -40.25, 100, and -34.59.

**Update 2**

After more research, it turns out that this is just the way the sqlite3 works. It returns a double (same as Ruby Float) to sqlite3-ruby and sqlite3-ruby just passes it on to Rails as a Float.  Then, Rails converts it to BigDecimal because the column type is decimal. Before Ruby 1.9, Ruby would round this number for us and we wouldn't see the problem.

Comment: Please update your question to specify what database server you're using and the driver you're using to access it.

Comment: This is in my test environment using sqlite3 (3.6.17) and I'm using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2).

Comment: I suspect sqlite3-ruby is creating a Float to return the value of the aggregate. Could you try casting the result to a string in the query to avoid this? I know it's not an ideal solution but it'll at least help isolate the issue.

Comment: Also: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4871-bigdecimal-comparison-failure-in-sqlite3_test-on-192-head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an elegant solution but you can bypass the creation of the Float object by casting the value of your aggregate calculation to TEXT in the query. This "fixes" the rounding error. Please update this question if you find a better solution (such as by patching the sqlite3-ruby driver).

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(amount) AS TEXT) FROM transactions WHERE envelope_id = 834498537
```

By casting to a string you're allowing Active Record to call BigDecimal's constructor which requires a string and bypassing Float with its inaccurate ISO floating point issues.

By the way, I doubt it's a good idea to name your table `transactions`. That's bound to conflict with some other class name or database-specific keyword at some point.

Comment: Thanks for all the help with this. This is a good solution for now. I submitted a bug for sqlite3-ruby. If I have time, I may fix it myself, but since I'm not using sqlite on production, I'm not going to worry about it too much now.