# why the result of Module.sum(:field) is integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
create table test_tables (
id number(38) primary key,
name varchar2(50),
age number(5),
gender varchar2(10),
point number(5,2)
);
insert into test_tables values (1,'name1',20,'male',80.5);
insert into test_tables values (2,'name2',21,'female',60.5);
insert into test_tables values (3,'name3',23,'male',90.5);
insert into test_tables values (4,'name4',19,'male',79.5);
insert into test_tables values (5,'name5',18,'female',80.5);
```

The result of TestTable.sum(:point) is 391,
why not 391.5?
I check rdoc,there are some description:

```
The value is returned with the same data type of the column
```

But in my case,the type of 'point' is number(5,2).
It's not a float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not especially familiar with SQLite but I think you should be using a DECIMAL type in your create table statement. More details:

[Active Record SQLite Type Mapping](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb#L109)
[SQLite Types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Be careful of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4591432/498798) though. It seems that  the sqlite3 ruby driver insists on creating Float ruby objects rather than BigDecimal for DECIMAL query results.